# Using a global thread pool in Android or just hijacking the one for async tasks

Tags: android, multithreading

I've been executing tasks like so:

```
LoginTask loginTask = new LoginTask(startActivityLayout, getApplicationContext(), usernameEdit, passwordEdit, progressBar);
loginTask.doInBackground();
```

which I now realize is probably an anti pattern -- it only works because I prefix every call to `doInBackground` with this...

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

So anyway, I tried to refactor it to use threads but I discovered -- that sucks!

Creating new threads every time I want to do something is super laggy and slow.

I *guess* this is because what I've been doing is hijacking threads from a big pre-existing pool that Android keeps around somewhere.

So I'm wondering - is there a more idiomatic way of hijacking those threads, or - should I create my own global thread pool - or - what's the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess this is because what I've been doing is hijacking threads from a big pre-existing pool that android keeps around somewhere

No, you have been doing all your work on the main application thread, freezing your UI. Basically, your `AsyncTask` is pointless.

> is there a more idiomatic way of hijacking those threads

You are not "hijacking" any threads.

> creating new threads every time I want to do something is super laggy and slow

We cannot help you with that, as your question does not contain any code demonstrating what you tried and explaining what specifically is "super laggy and slow".

> should I create my own global thread pool

Using an `Executor` of some form is certainly a possibility — see the `Executors` class for various factory methods (e.g., `newSingleThreadPool()`). So is using RxJava. When you eventually switch from Java to Kotlin, coroutines become an option.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might not need any of that. For example, the `StrictMode` hack you are using is frequently a reaction to getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Many networking libraries already exist with built-in threading support:

- OkHttp for general-purpose HTTP operations
- Retrofit for invoking REST-style Web services
- Apollo-Android for invoking GraphQL Web services
- Glide and Picasso for loading images
- etc.

So, you might consider whether one of those would allow you to reduce or eliminate the amount of thread management that you need to mess with yourself.

Comment: interesting, yeah I think it was from some kind of networking exception like that -- so then all these tasks are just executing on the main ui thread?

Comment: @smatthewenglish: If you are calling `doInBackground()` manually from the main application thread, `doInBackground()` will run on the main application thread. If you want `AsyncTask` to run `doInBackground()` on a background thread, do not call `doInBackground()` yourself. Call `execute()` or `executeOnExecutor()`. As I noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023445/thread-pool-in-android-calling-doinbackground-directly), `AsyncTask` is out of date. Wherever you are learning Android from is kinda old.

Comment: yeah man - I'm learning android from the oldest resource in the book --> EXPERIENCE -- also, in a sense I _was_ hijacking a thread pool, a thread pool of one, the main thread ;)